# Why does virtualbox interface need admin permission so many times?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have been using VirtualBox for 4 years now. I run it as a non-admin user and it worked fine. No admin permissions were required to run or boot up any VM.

Recently I installed the GenyMotion Android emulator on my host machine. It uses Virtualbox to create and run VMs. This genymotion needs admin permissions when I run the genymotion device manager. They say it is because it needs to create and/or access the VirtualBox interfaces (network interfaces). So every time I have to start genymotion, the admin permission (on Windows) pops up, and I have to enter the admin password. This keeps happening like 10-15 times (sometimes even more). What it does is that it creates multiple VirtualBox host-only ethernet adapters with these permissions (one for each adapter). It is really annoying to enter the password so many times. So instead, what I do is that I run Genymotion as administrator. So the admin permissions that were required for VirtualBox Interface are automatically granted.

The problem is that, now whenever I want to run a VM from VirtualBox manager, the same permissions pop up asking for admin privileges for the VirtualBox interface.

How can I get rid of these multiple admin permission pop-ups? I don't run VirtualBox as an admin and I don't want to.

Comment: If it needs admin permissions and you don't want to grant it admin permissions every time, you have to either run it as admin all the time or give up. There's no way to do administrative stuff without admin permissions.

Comment: Hi gronostaj. I understand that I need to grant admin permissions in some way. But my problem is not granting admin permissions but continuously do the same 15-20 times. As I said, the UAC pops up several times, I want to appear only once. Anyways, I think I have got the solution. Will post it if it is successful.